# How do change the name of the clang++ executable file?

Tags: vmware-player, clang

I'm using Vmware to run Ubuntu 14.04, and I recently updated the vmware player to version 7.1. I previously had clang installed, and everything was running fine. After I updated vmware, when I tried to compile using `clang++` I'd get this error:

The program `clang++` can be found in the following packages:

```
* clang-3.3
 * clang-3.4
 * clang-3.5
```

I reinstalled `llvm` and `clang 3.5`, but for some reason the executable installed with the name `clang++-3.5` in the `/usr/bin` directory, so whenever I want to compile something I have to use that command instead of the normal `clang++`. It's not a major problem (I don't think), but it's a pain. Why did this happen, and is there an easy way to fix it?

Comment: That's odd, given that the clang++-3.5 package has no such file: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/clang-3.5/filelist are you using a PPA?

Comment: First, I thought that clang had been removed in the update somehow. So I did the normal sudo apt-get install clang-3.5. It told me that I clang-3.5 was already installed. Then I removed it, and used the stable install from http://llvm.org/apt/.

Comment: @JustinRodriguez : One option is to create a symlink in /usr/bin as under :                                                                           
`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/clang++-3.5 /usr/bin/clang++`. 
This would have been the case usually. But, in your case, it doesn't seem so.